# $\{f_n \}$ is equicontinuous and pointwise converge to f is f uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $\{f_n \}$ is equicontinuous and pointwise converge to $f$ now 
is $f$ uniformly continuous ? I can prove f is continuous but is this uniformly continuous? and we know every $f_n$ is uniformly continuous. Is $ f_n$ uniformly convergent to $f$ ? prove or disprove.

Comment: What is the domain of the functions?

Comment: Certainly Arzelà–Ascoli theorem implies that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$, given the domain satisfies some mild conditions.

Comment: The domain is arbitrary metric space and it is not necessary to be compact.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $f$ that is not uniformly continuous.

Let $f_n = f+{1 \over n}$.

Then the $f_n$ are equicontinuous and converge pointwise to $f$ which is not uniformly continuous

Comment: So $f_n$ is not uniformly continuous and we know every $f_n$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: No. None of the $f,f_n$ are uniformly continuous. Shifting does not change the continuity properties.

Comment: Uniform continuity and equicontinuity are different things.

Comment: Equicontinuity implies uniform continuity of every member of the family. You say this is false?

Comment: Equicontinuity is a local property that applies to all members of the family, uniform continuity is a global property of a single function.

Comment: @amir bahadory Uniform equicontinuity does imply uniform continuity of all members. So, it depends on the definition of equicontinuity that you're using.